# Formatting lists in erlang

Tags: formatting, erlang

I am very new to erlang. I am trying to print a list to the console.

This is what I am able to do currently and stuck up.

I'm trying this out in the erl.

```
>List = [{"a",20},{"b", 30}].
[{"a",20},{"b",30}]
>lists:foreach( fun(H) -> io:format("~p~n", [H]) end, List).
{"a",20}
{"b",30}
```

I am interested in formatting each list there. I want the output to be of the form

```
"a" - 20
"b" - 30
```

I am not knowing how would I be able to access the lists in a list and format them as I want them to be. Any kind help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can *pattern match* the structure of the argument to `fun`:

```
1> List = [{"a",20},{"b", 30}].
[{"a",20},{"b",30}]
2> lists:foreach(fun({A, B}) -> io:format("~p - ~p~n", [A, B]) end, List).
"a" - 20
"b" - 30
ok
```

Comment: Awesome! I now get it. Thanks a lot!